# Как вырезать рандомные куски сообщения?

Tags: discord, discord.py

Хочу, чтобы типа из *Привет, это как пример* что-то получилось похожее на *Привет пример*, или в этом роде.
Вот кусочек из моего кода:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
     r = random.randint(0, 50)
     if r > 45:
        количествоаааа = random.randint(0, 200)
        соообщениееаавыафыва = await message.channel.history(limit=200).flatten() #
        if ("@everyone" or "@here" in message.content):
            await message.channel.send('кто-то хотел пингануть евриван или хере в сообщение, но я то троль, паэтаму mq шалава)))))')
        else:
            await message.channel.send(соообщениееаавыафыва[количествоаааа].content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике сообщений `on_message()` создадим список (`list`) `words`, который будет хранить отдельные слова сообщения, разделенные пробелом

```
words = message.content.split()
```

То есть, список `words` для такого текста (*"Это тестовый текст"*) будет выглядеть так:

```
['Это', 'тестовый', 'текст']
```

---

Затем, при условии, что в списке больше одного слова (иначе нет смысла удалять слова сообщения), создадим еще одну переменную `count_to_delete` - она будет хранить количество слов, которые мы хотим удалить.

Здесь немного математики)

Например, мы хотим удалить `50%` слов. Чтобы определить сколько это от общего числа, нужно разделить общее количество слов на `100` и умножить на `50`, а затем привести к целому числу (`int`), так как мы удалям именно целое число слов:

```
count_to_delete = int(len(words) / 100 * 50)
```

Таким образом, из списка `words` из 3 слов, приведенного выше, будет удалено `1` слово.

---

Чтобы определить какие именно слова удалять, подключим функцию `choice` из модуля `random`

```
from random import choice
```

Эта функция случайно выбирает один элемент из приведенного перечисляемого объекта.

Теперь, используя цикл `for` удалим случайные слова сообщения:

```
for i in range(count_to_delete):
    words.remove(choice(words))
```

---

На выходе получим список со случайно вырезанными словами. Чтобы снова привести его к строке и вернуть пробелы воспользуемся функцией `join()`:

```
result = ' '.join(words)
```

Строку `result` можно отправлять в канал дискорда.

---

**Полный код:**

```
from random import choice

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    # если автор сообщения - бот, то игнорируем сообщение
    if message.author.bot:
        return

    words = message.content.split()
    if len(words) > 1:
        count_to_delete = int(len(words) / 100 * 50)
        for i in range(count_to_delete):
            words.remove(choice(words))
        await message.channel.send(' '.join(words))
```

Comment: Чел, спасибо за этот ответ. Очень помог.